# Where can I find com.android.calendarcommon2

Tags: android, calendar

I have android project which I need to modify, but I cannot build it because one of its dependencies is missing.

import com.android.calendarcommon2.EventRecurrence;

I found in project.properties library reference ../CalendarCommon but I can't find that library.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I did find this: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/calendar/+/06b3293d5af3454a39681cfd659271551354b8a0/src/com/android/calendarcommon2

I also found this on github: https://github.com/xdtianyu/android-4.2_r1/tree/master/frameworks/opt/calendar/tests/src/com/android/calendarcommon2

it seems like this is a piece of the actual Android framework, can you be more specific about your problem?

What I think you should is delete the bin folder in your project then clean your project.
if your problem is not solved, probably problem is SDK files. You could try reinstalling the Android SDK.